Which integers can be expressed as $P(t)^2 + Q(t)^2 + R(t)^5$?
Inspired by this article and that one, I have two questions:
(1) Is the question of whether every integer can be expressed in the form $x^2 + y^2 + z^5$ ($x$, $y$, $z$ in $\mathbb{Z}$) an open problem?
(2) Which integers can be expressed in the form $P(t)^2 + Q(t)^2 + R(t)^5$, where $P(t)$, $Q(t)$, and $R(t)$ are non-constant polynomials with integer coefficients?
I managed to prove that the integers $k^{10}$, $2u^2k^{10}$, $-7k^{10}$, $-768k^{10}$ and $324k^{10}$ ($k$ and $u$ in $\mathbb{Z}$) satisfy the question (2) thanks to the following identities, obtained through trial and error and with the help of a computer :
$$(2t^4-2t^2+1)^2+(t^5-2t^3+2t)^2+(-t^2)^5=1$$
$$(4t^5-u)^2+(4t^5+u)^2+(-2t^2)^5=2u^2$$
$$(2t^4+38t^2+181)^2+(t^5+18t^3+82t)^2-(t^2+8)^5=-7$$
$$(2t^4+8t^2+16)^2+(t^5+8t^3+32t)^2-(t^2+4)^5=-768$$
$$(3t^4-18t^2+9)^2+(t^5-12t^3+27t)^2-(t^2-3)^5=324$$
But there are surely others, aren't there?
Update (22/08) : Other integers that satisfy (2) can be added to the list (see the chat).

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
